# loop in single.php of the same category

Tags: categories, loop, single

How can I put a loop in my single.php that shows the posts of the current category of the single and following the code structure that I have? The question comes, because I can not find the correct code.

I have tried with this code

```
<?php
 $categories = get_the_category($post->ID);
 if ( $categories ) {
 $category_ids = array();
 foreach ( $categories as $individual_category ) {
    $category_ids[] = $individual_category->term_id;
 }
$args=array(
    'category__in' => $category_ids,
    'post__not_in' => array($post->ID),
    'showposts'=>3, // Number of related posts that will be shown.
    'ignore_sticky_posts'=>1
);
$my_query = new wp_query( $args );
if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {

    echo '<h3>Related Articles</h3>'; // You can edit this
    echo '<ul>';

    while ($my_query->have_posts()) {
        $my_query->the_post();
        ?>
        <!-- do stuff -->

        <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>

        <?php
    }

    echo '</ul>';

 }
}
?>
```

But as is obvious, this would only give me the category with ID number 3, and I need it to be the same as the single post that is being viewed.

Thanks

**-EDIT-**

This is my full single.php code

```
<div class="container">
<div id="breadcrumbs">
    <?php if (function_exists('nav_breadcrumb')) nav_breadcrumb(); ?>

</div>


<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

    <div class="single">
        <div class="columns is-centered">
            <div class="column is-two-fifths is-content">
                <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
                <div class="title">
                    <?php the_title(); ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php the_content(); ?>
<?php endwhile; endif; ?>

<hr/>

<?php
$categories = get_the_category($post->ID);
if ($categories) {
    $category_ids = array();
    foreach ($categories as $individual_category) {
        $category_ids[] = $individual_category->term_id;
    }
    $args = array(
        'category__in' => $category_ids,
        'post__not_in' => array($post->ID),
        'showposts' => 3, // Number of related posts that will be shown.
        'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1
    );
    $my_query = new wp_query($args);
    if ($my_query->have_posts()) {

        echo '<h3>Related Articles</h3>'; // You can edit this
        echo '<ul>';

        while ($my_query->have_posts()) {
            $my_query->the_post();
            ?>
            <!-- do stuff -->

            <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>

            <?php
        }

        echo '</ul>';

    }
}
?></div>
```

Comment: Can you please share full source code?

Comment: for single.php?

Comment: Yes, I want to check how you have implemented. Because i have tried this code and it is working at my end.

Comment: @DarioB. `shows the posts of the current category of the single`. It was about displaying the title of posts from **any category** that is assigned to the currently displayed post?

Comment: @Bhupen now is my full code in the post

Comment: You have used this for custom post type?

Comment: @nmr no, i want to display all post for the same category as the post currently shown on the single. But only for this category.

Comment: @Bhupen similar, but this page is inherited from another developer, and in general is very poorly developed, I only look to implement this until I can make a better and updated project

Comment: "But as is obvious, this would only give me the category with ID number 3" That is not obvious at all. Nowhere in this code is there anything about a specific category ID.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest the following:

```
$categories   = get_the_category();
$category_ids = wp_list_pluck( $categories, 'term_id' );

$args = [
    'numberposts'  => 4,
    'category__in' => $category_ids,
];

$related_posts = get_posts( $args );
$related_posts = wp_list_filter( $related_posts, [ 'ID' => get_queried_oject_id() ], 'NOT' );

if ( count( $related_posts > 3 ) ) {
    array_pop( $related_posts );
}

global $post;

foreach ( $related_posts as $post ) {
    setup_postdata( $post );

    // Output posts.
}

wp_reset_postdata();
```

Note the following points about the code:

1. I use [`wp_list_pluck()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_list_pluck/) to get the category IDs in a single line.
2. I don't use `post__not_in`. This has known [performance issues](https://wpvip.com/documentation/performance-improvements-by-removing-usage-of-post__not_in/). Instead I query for 1 more post than we need so that we can remove the current post later if it appears in the results. This will be faster than using `post__not_in`.
3. I use `get_posts()` instead of `WP_Query`. This is because it has more appropriate defaults for secondary queries (such as setting `ignore_sticky_posts` and `no_found_rows` to `true`.
4. Once we have results I use `wp_list_filter()` to remove the current post, if it appears in the results. I do this by using `get_queried_oject_id()` to get the ID of the current post. If it doesn't appear in the results then I use `array_pop()` to remove the last post to get back down to 3 posts.

Answer (score -1):

If you are trying to get "Related Posts" by category for custom taxonomy then see the code given below:

```
$categories = get_the_terms($post->ID, 'your-taxonomy-name');
if ($categories) {
$category_ids = array();
foreach ($categories as $individual_category) {
    $category_ids[] = $individual_category->term_id;
}
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'your-post-type',
    'post__not_in' => array($post->ID),
    'showposts' => 3, // Number of related posts that will be shown.
    'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1,
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'your-taxonomy-name',
            'field' => 'id',
            'terms' => $category_ids,
            'operator'=> 'IN'
        )
    ),
);
$my_query = new wp_query($args);
```

Replace "your-taxonomy-name" and "your-post-type" with valid data.

Comment: With a large number of posts, post__not_in will kill performance.

Comment: But this is for single page so it will have only single post to include in post__not_in

Comment: I mean a total number of posts in the database.There was a question here not that long ago where somebody's site was extremely slow because a plugin was querying related posts like this. `post__not_in` is very inefficient. It'd be more performant to just remove the post from the results than to query with `post__not_in`.

Comment: I do not think this is the solution, because I am forced to assign a specific category, and what I need is to see all the posts in the current category.

Comment: This is not for assigning a category. You can try this and check.